# Strapi watchIgnoreFiles

Tags: strapi

My server always restarting when I edit an file in my project but I want to exclude the logs directory.

I've tried to use watchIgnoreFiles in my server.js but it doesn't work.

Can you help me thanks

[folders tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzmMT.png)

[server.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKU0I.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Strapi **v4** you need to move your `watchIgnoreFiles` setting from `server.js` to `admin.js`. To exclude the whole logs folder use this example:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  // some other variables are here
  watchIgnoreFiles: [
    '**/logs',
    './logs'
  ]
});
```

This forum thread may help as well: https://forum.strapi.io/t/change-file-without-triggering-a-reload-of-strapi/4026/7